# Appending result in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, append

I have this loop (which is part of a much bigger code) which outputs the price (HW2FPrice) of a bond for successive **SettleEvo** dates.
 How do get it to output a single array of HW2FPrice rather than lots of individual outputs? I would like the array to be **HW2FPrice Vs. SettleEvo**. Many thanks,

```
for SettleEvo = Settle:datenum('14-Mar-2013');
NumCouponsRemaining = cpncount(SettleEvo, Maturity, Period, Basis, 1, IssueDate); % Coupon payments remaining until maturity. Calculates the number of periods from start to finish.
nPeriods = NumCouponsRemaining;



[CFlowAmounts, CFlowDates] = cfamounts(CouponRate, SettleEvo, Maturity);
CFlowTimes = yearfrac(SettleEvo,CFlowDates);
CFlowZero = interp1(ZeroTimes,ZeroRates,CFlowTimes,'linear','extrap');
CFlowDF_Zero = zero2disc(CFlowZero,CFlowDates,SettleEvo);
Price_Zero = CFlowAmounts*CFlowDF_Zero';
[CFlowAmounts, CFlowDates, TFactors, Factors] = cfamounts(CouponRate,SettleEvo,repmat(Maturity,1,nTrials),Period,Basis);
CFlowDFSim = cumprod(exp(squeeze(-SimZeroRates(2:end,1,:).*stepSize)));
```

SimZeroRates is an array of (nPeriods,nTenors,nTrials);

```
Price_Ind = sum(CFlowAmounts(:,2:end).*CFlowDFSim',2);
HW2FPrice = mean(Price_Ind)
end
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking here - can you pare down the code and clarify what it is that you need?

Comment: I mainly want to store HW2FPrice in a single output rather than lots of single outputs. This would be good for me. The rest of the code is there to show how the SettleEvo date related to the other values which HW2FPrice depends on. This is just in case someone was able to go further and include in the outputs the respective SettleEvo date for each HW2FPrice that is given. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HW2FPrices = []; % creates an empty array

for SettleEvo = Settle:datenum('14-Mar-2013');
    % ... whatever other code is in your loop
    HW2FPrice = mean(Price_Ind)
    HW2FPrices(end+1) = HW2FPrice;
end
```

When the loop is done, `HW2FPrinces` will be an array containing all the `HW2FPrice` values you saw generated in your loop.

Comment: Hi this works great. Thanks very much. I did have to change HW2FPrices[end+1] to HW2FPrices(end+1) after getting an error message. But it works exactly as I need it. Really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: @Mary " I did have to change ..."  (Shaking fist in air)  ...JAVA! ...  OK I made the correctino in my answer for future generations.

Comment: Apologies.. Shows the level to which I know matlab given how much that confused me. I think I put it in as a "I did this, is that right?" kinda thing. And for the future generations that have my level of matlab sophistication. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mary no apologies necessary!  I'm not sorry you put in the time figuring out the right answer, that will pay off.  I was shaking my fist at the world that gives me Java using [] and matlab using () and a poor human brain that doesn't work quite like a computer but has to program them anyway.